# PayPal gateway has rejected request. Internal Error (#10001: Internal Error)

Tags: magento-1.7, paypal, backend, paypal-express

I have an issue while accept the payment for an order in  admin side. It shows the below error while accepting payment that is made using Paypal Standard, Paypal Payments pro.

`PayPal gateway has rejected request. Internal Error (#10001: Internal Error)`

[image]

How to fix this issue?
Any assistance will be helpful...

Comment: Have you enabled Paypal debugging? It may give you some clues.

Comment: @Tim I have enabled debug mode for `Basic Settings - PayPal Payments Pro` and `Basic Settings - PayPal Express Checkout` in `Payments Pro (Includes Express Checkout)` extension. But Still I am getting the same error. How to identify the issues using `debug mode`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I also received this error on testing Payments Pro in the sandbox. I sent a message to their support and got the following back:

> Internal Service Error is usually caused by using a credit card number
>   like 41111111111111111 etc, which has been used so many times in the
>   past in Sandbox environment. I would advise you to try one of the Visa
>   card numbers below:
>
> 4556852560405924 
>   4532011208755443 
>   4095054373873996 
>   4716638504906094

I had used the 41111111111111111 Visa test card (PayPal's published list of test cards here - http://www.paypalobjects.com/en_US/vhelp/paypalmanager_help/credit_card_numbers.htm). Presumably they could see I'd tried to use that card number from looking through their logs.

Anyhow, in my situation, using the above numbers worked fine for me - with no other changes in Magento or in my PayPal account.